# Laravel 8 - traverse very large database table and update record

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have got a Laravel 8 app. I would like to update a large database table from within my application. I added two new columns to the table and now I would like to update their content with the information of other columns per record.

My table has about 5.000.000 entries that need to be updated.

My problem is that the script being run from the browser either hits the memory exhaustion or the maximum execution time.

The controller function is as follows. I have set the retrieved number of rows to be limited to not run into the issues of time and memory.

```
public function fillDB()
{
    $entries = TABLE_MODEL::query()
                ->orWhereNull("number_correct")
                ->orWhereNull("number_wrong")
                ->limit(5000)
                ->get();

    foreach ($entries as $item) {
        $item->setNumberCorrect($item->getNumberCorrectWrong(true));
        $item->setNumberWrong($item->getNumberCorrectWrong(false));
        $item->save();
    }
}
```

I update the columns `number_correct` and `number_wrong` on each record where either one of these columns is still `NULL`. I cannot use a MySQL query to update the new columns, because I need to evaluate some information in each record to figure out the right values.

Is there another way of updating the table so I can run the update process at once?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[chunk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#selects)** method to iterate over large data as it only fetches the specified number of records at a time. You can use laravel **[commands](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#generating-commands)** instead of running it from the browser.

```
    $entries = TABLE_MODEL::query()
                ->orWhereNull("number_correct")
                ->orWhereNull("number_wrong")
                ->chunk(5000, function($entries) {
                    foreach ($entries as $item) {
                       $item->setNumberCorrect($item->getNumberCorrectWrong(true));
                       $item->setNumberWrong($item->getNumberCorrectWrong(false));
                       $item->save();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think **[Generator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php)** on PHP can be useful when you're working with very large datasets.

A generator allows us to circumvent memory limit concerns by iterating over data without first building up a large array in memory.

**EDIT :**

Back with more details about Generators on Laravel collection using [cursor()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#cursors) , for your example it will be something like :

```
public function fillDB()
{
    $entries = TABLE_MODEL::query()
                ->orWhereNull("number_correct")
                ->orWhereNull("number_wrong")
                ->cursor();

    foreach ($entries as $item) {
        $item->setNumberCorrect($item->getNumberCorrectWrong(true));
        $item->setNumberWrong($item->getNumberCorrectWrong(false));
        $item->save();
    }
}
```

*I Just replaced get() with cursor() and removed the limit.*

Comment: Can ```cursor()``` be used with DB queries (query builder) ??

Answer (score 1):

Using chunk could still lead to memory issues, at least in pre v8. This is because query results are buffered and kept in memory. In order to avoid this, and clearing memory after each chunk, you can add the following statement before you start iterating. I'm not sure this behaviour is still the case in v8, but it's worth to give it a try in your use case.

```
\DB::getPdo()->setAttribute(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);
```

More information in this Laravel framework [Github issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14919)